# problem using the xsl method for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSL I am trying to turn this XML:

```
<book><title>This is a <b>great</b> book</title></book>
```

into this XML:

```
<book>This is a <bold>great</bold> book</book>
```

using this xsl:

```
<xsl:for-each select="book/title/*">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name() = 'b'">
        <bold>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </bold>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but my output is looking like this:

```
<book><bold>great</bold></bold>
```

Can anyone explain why the root text of `<title>` is getting lost? I believe my for-each select statement may need to be modified but I can't figure out what is should be.

Keep in mind that I cannot use an `<xsl:template match>` because of the complexity of my style sheet.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the above XSL code inside an xsl:template?  If so, can you add that code?

Comment: @Pavel's answer is correct; however, the way you're approaching the problem seems awfully brittle (i.e. non-general and liable to break the minute something about your input file changes).  You might consider describing the problem in more detail.

Comment: +1 for a well-written question

Comment: Jim is right; broadly speaking, it's worth considering what happens if you have e.g. this input: `<book><title>This is a <b><i>great</i></b> book</title></book>` - note the nested `<i>`. A single `xsl:for-each` loop, as in your code, won't handle this - it has to be recursive. As a side note, regardless of the complexity of your stylesheet, you could still use `xsl:template` here (which would also buy you recursion cheaply) if you use a distinct `mode` to avoid clashes with existing templates.

Comment: Good point about using a mode, thanks pavel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This XPath expression:

```
book/title/*
```

means "all child *elements* of `book/title`". In your case, `book/title` has 3 child *nodes*:

- Text node: `This is a`
- Element node: `<b>...</b>`
- Text node: `book`

As you can see, only one of them is an element, and gets selected. If you want to get all child nodes, both text and elements, use this:

```
book/title/node()
```

If you want to get text nodes separately, use this:

```
book/title/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

While Pavel Minaev provided the answer to the question, **it must be noted that this question demonstrates a really bad approach** (probably due to lack of experience) **to XSLT procesing**.

The task can be accomplished in an elegant way, which demonstrates the power of XSLT:

When the above transformation is applied on the provided XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title/b">
      <bold>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </bold>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the wanted result is produced:

```
<book><title>This is a <b>great</b> book</title></book>
```

**This is a good illustration of one of the basic XSLT design patterns -- overriding the identity rule for elment renaming/flattening**.

Comment: Well, he stated that "keep in mind that I cannot use an `<xsl:template match>` because of the complexity of my style sheet" in the question, which I suspect means that he tried to do it with templates, and found that it clashed with existing rules. If so, `mode` should fix that.

Comment: @pavel-minaev Probably he had poblems, but such bad code should not be let uncommented, or other people would think it was a good example :)